# Re-arranging data for GLM analysis in R using a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I think my question is fairly simple to answer but I'm learning R so I'd like to know the best way to do it.

I've a dataset looking like this:

```
> print(agg_df41367)
# A tibble: 72 x 3
# Groups:   hour [24]
    hour predicted      y
 1     0 Feeding   0.121 
 2     0 Foraging  0.632 
 3     0 Standing  0.300 
 4     1 Feeding   0.141 
 5     1 Foraging  0.727 
 6     1 Standing  0.183 
 7     2 Feeding   0.0932
 8     2 Foraging  0.817 
 9     2 Standing  0.133 
10     3 Feeding   0.214
```

I would like to run a GLM model, so I'd like my data to look like:

```
head(agg_df41361_GLM)
hour Foraging Standing Feeding 
0     0.632   0.300    0.121
1     0.727   0.183    0.141
2     0.817   0.133    0.0932
3     etc.    etc.      0.214
```

Any ideas of what is the most compact way to do this? Ideally, I would like to use a `for`-loop to compute this transformation for multiple datasets. All my datasets follow a name format `agg_df4136*`. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: This is the kind of problem where loops are really quite inefficient. If you have multple data frames with similar structures and column names it's more worthwhile to put them in to a list and then use `lapply()` or similar higher-order functions. If column names and structure are different look in to creating a custom function where you can adjust parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to reshape the dataset you posted.

```
library(tidyr)

# example data
dt = read.table(text = "
hour predicted      y
1     0 Feeding   0.121 
2     0 Foraging  0.632 
3     0 Standing  0.300 
4     1 Feeding   0.141 
5     1 Foraging  0.727 
6     1 Standing  0.183 
7     2 Feeding   0.0932
8     2 Foraging  0.817 
9     2 Standing  0.133 
", header=T)

spread(dt, predicted, y)

#   hour Feeding Foraging Standing
# 1    0  0.1210    0.632    0.300
# 2    1  0.1410    0.727    0.183
# 3    2  0.0932    0.817    0.133
```

If you have multiple datasets it's better to create a list of them and apply the reshaping process to each one of them:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example of list of dataframes
l = list(dt, dt, dt)

map(l, ~spread(., predicted, y))

# [[1]]
# hour Feeding Foraging Standing
# 1    0  0.1210    0.632    0.300
# 2    1  0.1410    0.727    0.183
# 3    2  0.0932    0.817    0.133
# 
# [[2]]
# hour Feeding Foraging Standing
# 1    0  0.1210    0.632    0.300
# 2    1  0.1410    0.727    0.183
# 3    2  0.0932    0.817    0.133
# 
# [[3]]
# hour Feeding Foraging Standing
# 1    0  0.1210    0.632    0.300
# 2    1  0.1410    0.727    0.183
# 3    2  0.0932    0.817    0.133
```

Note that here I'm using the same dataset (`dt`) as my 3 list elements, but it will work with different datasets, as long as you have the same column names.

If you want to create a list of all your datasets that start with the name pattern you provided you can do this:

```
# get objects that start with this name pattern
input_names = ls()[grepl("^agg_df4136", ls())]

# get the data that match those names
list_datasets = map(input_names, get)
```

So, `list_datasets` is a list of all dataframes in your environment with a name that starts with "agg_df4136".

Comment: Hello, I'm getting: ```> list_GLM = list(agg_df41361_GLM, agg_df41365_GLM, 
+                 agg_df41366_GLM,agg_df41366bis_GLM,agg_df41367_GLM,agg_df41368_GLM)
> list_GLM<-map(list_GLM, ~spread(., predicted, y))
Error in numeric(nrowz) : invalid 'length' argument``` Any idea? Sorry that I have no experience with lists..

Comment: Not sure, because I don't have the data. You should spot which dataset within your list creates this issue. Start with one dataset, then check 2, etc. until you spot the issue